# PayPal product creation using .net

Tags: c#, .net, paypal, paypal-subscriptions

I am trying to intagrate PayPal in my application. I want to create product but there is no `.net` sdk available for it. I  want to integrate it in `asp.net` core web application. I have gone through documentation is there any other way to create subscriptions. For subscription I have to first create product and then plan. I don't have any code because I am confused. I am using following link

[Reference Link](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/business/subscriptions/#2-create-plan)

Comment: And what is your problem / challenge?

Comment: I don't how to achieve it using c#

Comment: Well the documentation contains all the necessary HTTP calls in cURL syntax. You have to "translate" them into C# by using the [`HttpClient`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient?view=net-5.0)

Comment: Wouldn't it make sense to post the question and the answer with the same account, or are you actually two different _Muhammad Kamran's_?

Comment: I am not sure what bothers you the most my question or the same name. Well actually we are two different Muhammad Kamran with different accounts. If you have any kind of confusion please make yourself clear.

Comment: I got my answer that is what I was looking for It doesn't matter who or where from someone answered my question If he/she had a name same to my name or not I think this doesn't even matter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As there are no SDKs for the current Subscriptions APIs, use a direct HTTP integration.  Here is a sample in C# with HttpClient:

```
using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
{
    using (var request = new HttpRequestMessage(new HttpMethod("POST"), "https://api-m.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/catalogs/products"))
    {
        request.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("Authorization", "Bearer <Access-Token>");
        request.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("PayPal-Request-Id", "PRODUCT-18062020-001"); 

        request.Content = new StringContent("{\n  \"name\": \"Service Name\",\n  \"description\": \"Description\",\n  \"type\": \"SERVICE\",\n  \"category\": \"SOFTWARE\",\n}");
        request.Content.Headers.ContentType = MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("application/json"); 

        var response = await httpClient.SendAsync(request);
    }
}
```

Products and plans can also be managed manually in the web interface

- Sandbox - https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/billing/plans
- Live - https://www.paypal.com/billing/plans